# How do units of mm^2/mm represent the reinforcing steel area in a slab?

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-engineering, reinforced-concrete

Whenever I've come across notation for specifying how much reinforcing steel is in a member, it is typically by giving the area of steel as a percent of the cross-sectional area of the member.

[image]

For example in this picture, you could say that the reinforcing steel is `0.02` or `2%`. You could also specify the reinforcing steel given a schedule, e.g. `#8 @ 12" O.C`.

I recently came across a piece of software that was asking for the reinforcing steel of a floor slab in units of `mm^2/mm`. I cannot figure out how they came across those units. How could I calculate the reinforcement in these units given I know how much steel is in the slab in the other conventions I listed earlier?

Comment: Re: Rollback of revision 3, [related discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20424311#20424311).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second bar description is what you need to compare it to:

> #8 @ 12" O.C.

A #8 bar is 0.79 in<sup>2</sup>. This gives us $\frac{0.79in^2}{12in}$ or in<sup>2</sup> over in. This is the similar to your mm<sup>2</sup>/mm. (Obviously the units are not interchangeable!)

This method of describing reinforcing is useful if you don't care about the actual size of rebar used. It could be #8 at 12" or #6 at 6.625".

Comment: mm2/mm is not going to be the same as in2/in, you'll be out by a factor or 25.4. 1 inch = 25.4 mm. 1 in2/in is (25.4)^2/25.4 mm2/mm = 25.4 mm2/mm